# Can't run a Servlet with Tomcat because something is using the ports

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm trying to write a Servlet in eclipse configured to use Tomcat 5.5 and I get the following error when I try to run it:

> Several ports (8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v5.5 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s)

As far as I know, Tomcat 5.5 is the one using port 8080, and when I go to http://localhost:8080 I do get the Tomcat success page, so it looks like eclipse tries to run another instance of Tomcat without shutting down the original and fails. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like it says, something is using the port.

there are two solutions for your problem.

1. identify (on windows with netstat command) what is using the port (e.g. skype, ...) and stop it
2. change the port of your tomcat runtime in eclipse -> http://techteam.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/changing-the-tomcat-port-settings-in-eclipse/

hope this helps